# Does ungetc() not write to a file, but only move file position?

Tags: c, io

In the standard C library, does ungetc() not write to a file?

Does it only move file position?

Can it be used without any reading beforehand? i.e. can it be used independently of other IO functions?

Can it be used after a reading function which is not necessary a one-character-at-a-time, i.e. which reads more than a character at a time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`ungetc` is a read function. It does not do any writing. The file might not even be open for writing.

It doesn't matter what you did beforehand. The `ungetc` function only affects future reads.

If the next read is a block read then it will read the characters pushed by `ungetc` first.

If you `ungetc` some characters and then read those characters, the file position indicator returns to where it was.

While there are pushed-back characters you haven't read yet, then:

- For a text stream, the file position indicator is *unspecified*
- For a binary stream, the file position indicator is subtracted by `1` for each pushed-back character; becoming *indeterminate* if it tries to go back from `0`.

If you have any other questions, they may be answered by the description of `ungetc` in [the C Standard](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.7.10):

Comment: Nice!.  Something to add "If the value of c equals that of the macro EOF, the operation fails and the input stream is unchanged."

Comment: Thanks. "For a text stream, the file position indicator is unspecified", what does that mean?

Comment: @Tim it could be anything